# Upper semi continuous equivalence

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, semicontinuous-functions

I have a doubt about upper semicontinuous functions. I have two definitions and I need to show that they are equivalente.

$f$ is upper semi-continuous at $x_{0}$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$, exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)<f(x_0)+\varepsilon$ if $x \in (x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$.

For the particular case of a metric space, I need to prove that $f$ is upper semicontinuous in $x_0$ if and only if

$$ \limsup _{x\to x_{0}}f(x)\leq f(x_{0}).$$

Thanks for any help,

Cleto

Comment: What is confusing you about this? The first is very close to being the definition of the second when the space is the real line. (Not quite the definition, but close enough that the rest is pretty straight-forward.)

Answer (score 0):

I realised that it was just a calculus exercise. I will indicate the answer. Maybe it will be usefull for someone. Thanks for the comments.

Suppose that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that 
$x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta ) \cap X$ implies $f(x) \leq f(x_0) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$

Let $c$ and $(x_n) \in X \backslash \{x_0\}$ such that $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_n = x_0}$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_n)} = c$. Let  $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>n_0 \Rightarrow \left|x_n - x_0\right| < \delta \ \textrm{e} \ \left|f(x_n) -c\right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ 
If  $n>n_0$, as $f$ is upper semicontinuous at $x_0$, we have
    $ c -\frac{\epsilon}{2} < f(x_n) < f(x_0) +\frac{\epsilon}{2}$
    In this way, we have $c < f(x_0) + \epsilon. $ As $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $f(x_0)$ is an aderence value and, as $c$ is arbitrary $ \limsup_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x) \leq f(x_0),  $ as we want to show.

On the other hand, if $ \limsup_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x) \leq f(x_0),  $, the biggest aderence avalue of $f$ at $x_0$ is shorter than  $f(x_0)$. This way, with the exception of a finite number of values, $(f(x_n))$ with $(x_n) \rightarrow x_0$ is shorter than $f(x_0)$. Let us consider only subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ bunded by  $f(x_0)$.
    Suppose that $f$ is not upper semicontinuous at $x_0$, and that exists  $\epsilon>0$ such that, for all $\delta >0$, there exists $x \in X$, 
$\left|x-x_0\right|< \delta$, such that $f(x_0) + \epsilon \leq f(x)$.
    We can define a sequence such that $\left|x_n-x_0\right| < \frac{1}{n}$ satisfies  $f(x_0) + \epsilon \leq f(x_n).$ Then, the sequence  $(f(x_n))$ is lower bounded and has a convergent subsequence $(f(x_{n_k}))$. Let $c = \displaystyle{\lim_{n_k \rightarrow \infty} f(x_{n_k})}$. By our construction, $f(x_0) \leq c$. As $c$ is an adherence valueof $(f(x_n))$, we conclude that
    $f(x_0) \leq c \leq \limsup_{x\rightarrow x_0} f(x),  $ a contradiction.